# how to build stylesheet to use with xsltproc to convert xml to csv

Tags: xml, linux, bash, csv, xslt

Need to convert xml file to csv using the bash shell. checked we have xsltproc available on the linux host. if there are any other ways to convert this to csv through bash shell. please let me know. 
xml file is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0' encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns1:CommunicationHistoryResponse xmlns:nsl="http://www.itc.com/bd" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<ns1:NumPagesAvailable>10</ns1:NumPagesAvailable>
<ns1:Reason>
  <ns1:ReasonCode>REQ_SUCCESS</ns1:ReasonCode>
<ns1:ReasonDescription>Fetch Communication History 
Successful</ns1:ReasonDescription>
</ns1:Reason>
<ns1:CommunicationHistoryList>
<ns1:CommunicationHistory>
 <ns1:lastModified>2019-03-18T00:00:10+00:00:00</ns1:lastModified>
 <ns1:id>290805235</ns1:id>
 <ns1:cLIName>null</ns1:cLIName>
 <ns1:cLINumber>null</ns1:cLINumber>
 <ns1:buttonNumber>1</ns1:buttonNumber>
 <ns1:callType>resource</ns1:callType>
 <ns1:callUsage>none</ns1:callUsage>
 <ns1:destination>null</ns1:destination>
 <ns1:deviceChannel>7</ns1:deviceChannel>
 <ns1:deviceChannelType>Speaker</ns1:deviceChannelType>
 <ns1:deviceIdId>268435490</ns1:deviceIdId>
 <ns1:displayInCallHistory>true</ns1:displayInCallHistory>
 <ns1:duration>27</ns1:duration>
 <ns1:e164Destination xsi:nill="true" />
 <ns1:eventType>Initiated</ns1:eventType>
 <ns1:parentUserCDIId>369098755</ns1:parentUserCDIId>
 <ns1:personalPointofContactId>0</ns1:personalPointofContactId>
 <ns1:pointofContactId>0</ns1:pointofContactId>
 <ns1:priority>none</ns1:priority>
 <ns1:reasonForDisconnect xsi:nil="true" />
 <ns1:resourceAORId>33563751</ns1:resourceAORId>
 <ns1:rolloverAppearance>1</ns1:rolloverAppearance>
 <ns1:routedDestination></ns1:routedDestination>
 <ns1:schemaDifference_blob_reserved xsi:nil="true" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
 <ns1:schemaDifference_reserved>{}</ns1:schemaDifference_reserved>
 <ns1:startTime>2019-03-17T23:59:43+00:00</ns1:startTime>
 <ns1:trunkBchannel>-1</ns1:trunkBchannel>
 <ns1:trunkId>335543181</ns1:trunkId>
 <ns1:userId>33454412</ns1:userid>
 </ns1:CommunicationHistory>
  <ns1:CommunicationHistory>
 <ns1:lastModified>2019-02-18T00:00:10+00:00:00</ns1:lastModified>
 <ns1:id>290805245</ns1:id>
 <ns1:cLIName>null</ns1:cLIName>
 <ns1:cLINumber>null</ns1:cLINumber>
 <ns1:buttonNumber>2</ns1:buttonNumber>
 <ns1:callType>resource</ns1:callType>
 <ns1:callUsage>none</ns1:callUsage>
 <ns1:destination>null</ns1:destination>
 <ns1:deviceChannel>7</ns1:deviceChannel>
 <ns1:deviceChannelType>Speaker</ns1:deviceChannelType>
 <ns1:deviceIdId>268436230</ns1:deviceIdId>
 <ns1:displayInCallHistory>true</ns1:displayInCallHistory>
 <ns1:duration>26</ns1:duration>
 <ns1:e164Destination xsi:nill="true" />
 <ns1:eventType>Initiated</ns1:eventType>
 <ns1:parentUserCDIId>369198755</ns1:parentUserCDIId>
 <ns1:personalPointofContactId>0</ns1:personalPointofContactId>
 <ns1:pointofContactId>0</ns1:pointofContactId>
 <ns1:priority>none</ns1:priority>
 <ns1:reasonForDisconnect xsi:nil="true" />
 <ns1:resourceAORId>33552751</ns1:resourceAORId>
 <ns1:rolloverAppearance>1</ns1:rolloverAppearance>
 <ns1:routedDestination></ns1:routedDestination>
 <ns1:schemaDifference_blob_reserved xsi:nil="true" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
 <ns1:schemaDifference_reserved>{}</ns1:schemaDifference_reserved>
 <ns1:startTime>2019-02-17T23:59:43+00:00</ns1:startTime>
 <ns1:trunkBchannel>-1</ns1:trunkBchannel>
 <ns1:trunkId>335543191</ns1:trunkId>
 <ns1:userId>33454413</ns1:userid>
 </ns1:CommunicationHistory>
 </ns1:CommunicationHistoryList>
 </nsl:CommunicationHistoryResponse>
```

I tried building the XSL stylesheet with no avail. below is the details of stylesheet i tried. root is on ns1:CommunicationHistoryResponse.
ns1:NumPagesAvailable,ns1:ReasonCode,ns1:ReasonDescription can be repeated for each underlying record.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:template match="/root"> ns1:lastModified; 
 ns1:id;ns1:cLIName;ns1:cLINumber;ns1:buttonNumber;ns1:callType;
 ns1:callUsage;ns1:destination;ns1:deviceChannel;
 ns1:deviceChannelTypeSpeaker;
 ns1:deviceIdId;
 ns1:displayInCallHistory;
 ns1:duration;
 ns1:e164Destination;
 ns1:eventType;
 ns1:parentUserCDIId;
 ns1:personalPointofContactId;
 ns1:pointofContactId;
 ns1:priority;
 ns1:reasonForDisconnect;
 ns1:resourceAORId;
 ns1:rolloverAppearance;
 ns1:routedDestination;
 ns1:schemaDifference_blob_reserved;
 ns1:schemaDifference_reserved;
 ns1:startTime;
 ns1:trunkBchannel;
 ns1:trunkId;
 ns1:userId
 <xsl:for-each select="record">
 <xsl:for-each select="data"><xsl:value-of select="ns1:lastModified"/>;
 <xsl:value-of select="ns1:id"/>"/>;
 <xsl:value-of select="ns1:cLIName"/>"/>;
 <xsl:value-of select="ns1:cLINumber"/>;
 <xsl:value-of select="ns1:buttonNumber"/>;
 <xsl:value-of select="ns1:callType"/>;
 <xsl:value-of select="ns1:callUsage"/>;
 <xsl:value-of select="ns1:destination"/>;
 <xsl:value-of select="ns1:deviceChannel"/>;
 <xsl:value-of select="ns1:deviceChannelTypeSpeaker"/>;
 <xsl:value-of select="ns1:deviceIdId"/>;
 <xsl:value-of select="ns1:displayInCallHistory"/>;
 <xsl:value-of select="ns1:duration"/>;
 <xsl:value-of select="ns1:e164Destination"/>;
 <xsl:value-of select="ns1:eventType"/>;
 <xsl:value-of select="ns1:parentUserCDIId"/>;
 <xsl:value-of select="ns1:personalPointofContactId"/>;
 <xsl:value-of select="ns1:pointofContactId"/>;
 <xsl:value-of select="ns1:priority"/>;
 <xsl:value-of select="ns1:reasonForDisconnect"/>;
 <xsl:value-of select="ns1:resourceAORId"/>;
 <xsl:value-of select="ns1:rolloverAppearance"/>;
 <xsl:value-of select="ns1:routedDestination"/>;
 <xsl:value-of select="ns1:schemaDifference_blob_reserved"/>;
 <xsl:value-of select="ns1:schemaDifference_reserved"/>;
 <xsl:value-of select="ns1:startTime"/>;
 <xsl:value-of select="ns1:trunkBchannel"/>;
 <xsl:value-of select="ns1:trunkId"/>;
 <xsl:value-of select="ns1:userId"/>
 <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text></xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

```
ns1:NumPagesAvailable,ns1:ReasonCode,ns1:ReasonDescription, ns1:lastModified,ns1:id,ns1:cLIName,ns1:cLINumber,ns1:buttonNumber,ns1:callType,ns1:callUsage,ns1:destination,ns1:deviceChannel,ns1:deviceChannelType,ns1:deviceIdId,ns1:displayInCallHistory,ns1:duration,ns1:e164Destination,ns1:eventType,ns1:parentUserCDIId,ns1:personalPointofContactId,ns1:pointofContactId,ns1:priority,ns1:reasonForDisconnect,ns1:resourceAORId,ns1:rolloverAppearance,ns1:routedDestination,ns1:schemaDifference_blob_reserved,ns1:schemaDifference_reserved,ns1:startTime,ns1:trunkBchannel,ns1:trunkId,ns1:userId
10,REQ_SUCCESS,Fetch Communication History Successful,2019-03-18T00:00:10+00:00:00,290805235,,,1,resource,none,
```

Comment: Please fix your input example to be a well-formed XML document. `ns1` is not the same thing as `nsl`.

Comment: fixed the nsl to ns1 mike.

Answer (score 0):

Without testing, two things stand out immediately:

1. Your template matches `/root` - but your input has no such element;
   the root element's name is `nsl:CommunicationHistoryResponse` ;
2. You are using a prefix `ns1` without bounding it to a namespace first.